# Minecraft Error

Tags: java, minecraft

I don't know what the problem is, I can launch Minecraft, but it redirects me to an error window. Here's the source code:

```
package net.minecraft.src;

import java.util.Random;

public class mod_PixelatedExtension extends BaseMod {

    public static final Item EmeraldSword = new ItemSword(10000,
            EnumToolMaterial.MOD_EMERALD).setItemName("Emerald Sword");
    public static final Item EmeraldPickaxe = new ItemPickaxe(10001,
            EnumToolMaterial.MOD_EMERALD).setItemName("Emerald Pickaxe");
    public static final Item EmeraldAxe = new ItemAxe(10002,
            EnumToolMaterial.MOD_EMERALD).setItemName("Emerald Axe");
    public static final Item EmeraldShovel = new ItemSpade(10003,
            EnumToolMaterial.MOD_EMERALD).setItemName("Emerald Shovel");
    public static final Item EmeraldHoe = new ItemHoe(10004,
            EnumToolMaterial.MOD_EMERALD).setItemName("Emerald Hoe");

    public static final Item AmethystGem = new Item(10005).setItemName(
            "Amethyst Gem").setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabMaterials);
    public static final Block AmethystOre = new BlockAmethyst(151, 0)
            .setHardness(6F).setResistance(7.0F).setBlockName("Amethyst Ore");

    public static final Block RubyOre = new BlockRuby(151, 0).setHardness(6F)
            .setResistance(7.0F).setBlockName("Ruby Ore");
    public static final Item RubyGem = new Item(10006).setItemName("Ruby Gem")
            .setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabMaterials);

    public void generateSurface(World world, Random random, int chunkX,
            int chunkZ) {
        Random randomGenerator = random;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // Ore Generator för Amethyst (BlockAmethyst.java)
            int randPosX = chunkX + randomGenerator.nextInt(20);
            int randPosY = random.nextInt(20);
            int randPosZ = chunkZ + randomGenerator.nextInt(20);

            (new WorldGenMinable(AmethystOre.blockID, 4)).generate(world,
                    random, randPosX, randPosY, randPosZ);

        }

    }

    public void load() {

        // Emerald

        // Emerald svärdet
        EmeraldSword.iconIndex = ModLoader.addOverride("/gui/items.png",
                "/items/EmeraldSword.png");
        ModLoader.addName(EmeraldSword, "Emerald Sword");
        ModLoader.addRecipe(new ItemStack(EmeraldSword, 1), new Object[] {
                " * ", " * ", " X ", 'X', Item.blazeRod, '*', Item.emerald });

        // Emerald Picka
        EmeraldPickaxe.iconIndex = ModLoader.addOverride("/gui/items.png",
                "/items/EmeraldPick.png");
        ModLoader.addName(EmeraldPickaxe, "Emerald Pickaxe");
        ModLoader.addRecipe(new ItemStack(EmeraldPickaxe, 1), new Object[] {
                "***", " X ", " X ", 'X', Item.blazeRod, '*', Item.emerald });

        // Emerald Axe
        EmeraldAxe.iconIndex = ModLoader.addOverride("/gui/items.png",
                "/items/EmeraldAxe.png");
        ModLoader.addName(EmeraldAxe, "Emerald Axe");
        ModLoader.addRecipe(new ItemStack(EmeraldAxe, 1), new Object[] { "** ",
                "*X ", " X ", 'X', Item.blazeRod, '*', Item.emerald });

        // Emerald Shovel
        EmeraldShovel.iconIndex = ModLoader.addOverride("/gui/items.png",
                "/items/EmeraldShovel.png");
        ModLoader.addName(EmeraldShovel, "Emerald Shovel");
        ModLoader.addRecipe(new ItemStack(EmeraldShovel, 1), new Object[] {
                " * ", " X ", " X ", 'X', Item.blazeRod, '*', Item.emerald });

        // Emerald Hoe
        EmeraldHoe.iconIndex = ModLoader.addOverride("/gui/items.png",
                "/items/EmeraldHoe.png");
        ModLoader.addName(EmeraldHoe, "Emerald Hoe");
        ModLoader.addRecipe(new ItemStack(EmeraldHoe, 1), new Object[] { "** ",
                " X ", " X ", 'X', Item.blazeRod, '*', Item.emerald });

        // Amethyst Gem

        AmethystGem.iconIndex = ModLoader.addOverride("/gui/items.png",
                "/items/Amethyst.png");
        ModLoader.addName(AmethystGem, "Amethyst Gem");

        // Amethyst Ore
        ModLoader.registerBlock(AmethystOre);
        AmethystOre.blockIndexInTexture = ModLoader.addOverride("/terrain.png",
                "/items/AmethystOre.png");
        ModLoader.addName(AmethystOre, "Amethyst Ore");

        // Amethyst Ore ---> Amethyst Gem
        ModLoader.addSmelting(AmethystOre.blockID, new ItemStack(
                mod_PixelatedExtension.AmethystGem, 1), 1.0F);

        // Ruby Ore
        ModLoader.registerBlock(RubyOre);
        RubyOre.blockIndexInTexture = ModLoader.addOverride("/terrain.png",
                "/items/RubyOre.png");
        ModLoader.addName(RubyOre, "Ruby Ore");

        // Ruby Gem
        RubyGem.iconIndex = ModLoader.addOverride("/gui/items.png",
                "/items/RubyGem.png");
        ModLoader.addName(RubyGem, "Ruby Gem");

        // Ruby Ore ---> Ruby Gem
        ModLoader.addSmelting(AmethystOre.blockID, new ItemStack(
                mod_PixelatedExtension.RubyGem, 1), 1.0F);

    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return "3.14159265";
    }
}
```

Following lines are shown in the console (Eclipse):

```
27 achievements
210 recipes
Setting user: Player731, -
Client asked for parameter: server
LWJGL Version: 2.4.2
ModLoader 1.4.7 Initializing...
Failed to load mod from "mod_PixelatedExtension.class"
Someone is closing me!
```

I don't know how to give you anymore hints, I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: no more error messages than `Failed to load mod from "mod_PixelatedExtension.class"`?

Comment: Does the java compiler say something?

Comment: Try clean&build. Once I encountered a random `ClassNotFoundException` that clean&build solved.

Comment: Try removing your mods then run minecraft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some extension in mod_PixelatedExtension.class is missing, it's probably because you have a new line that's not included in "mod_PixelatedExtension.class" or written some name of an item incorrectly. Start checking what you modified from the previous stable version.